# insert Tuples into SQlite database

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to insert tuples from a list made up of tuples into a SQlite Database. I don't even get an error code, it just doesn't insert anything.

`for tpl in tuplelist:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO GUV
                        (Jahr, Ertrag, Betriebskosten, Bruttobetriebsgewinn, Forschung_und_Entwicklung,
                         Vertriebs_und_Verwaltungskosten, Personalkosten, Abschreibung_und_Abgrenzungen,
                         Sonstige_Betriebskosten, Geschäftsaufwand, Betriebseinnahmen_vor_Zinsen_und_Steuern,
                         Neutrale_Erträge, Gewinn_vor_Einkommenssteuer, Steueraufwand,
                         Nettogewinn_für_weitere_Geschäftstätigkeit, Nettogewinn, Nettogewinn_verfügbar_für_Aktionäre,
                         Unverwässert, Verwässert)
                         VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? ,? , ?, ?, ?, ? )''', tpl)`

EDIT: I wanted to add this. I am not trying to insert strings, but a tuple with integers in it. The table I want to insert it into looks like this:

`CREATE TABLE GUV(
    Jahr                                        INTEGER,
    Ertrag                                      INTEGER,
    Betriebskosten                              INTEGER,
    Bruttobetriebsgewinn                        INTEGER,
    Forschung_und_Entwicklung                   INTEGER,
    Vertriebs_und_Verwaltungskosten             INTEGER,
    Personalkosten                              INTEGER,
    Abschreibung_und_Abgrenzungen               INTEGER,
    Sonstige_Betriebskosten                     INTEGER,
    Geschäftsaufwand                            INTEGER,
    Betriebseinnahmen_vor_Zinsen_und_Steuern    INTEGER,
    Neutrale_Erträge                            INTEGER,
    Gewinn_vor_Einkommenssteuer                 INTEGER,
    Steueraufwand                               INTEGER,
    Nettogewinn_für_weitere_Geschäftstätigkeit  INTEGER,
    Nettogewinn                                 INTEGER,
    Nettogewinn_verfügbar_für_Aktionäre         INTEGER,
    Unverwässert                                INTEGER,
    Verwässert                                  INTEGER
)`

EDIT: Guys it's solved, I just forgot to commit

Answer (score 0):

Hi UFO and welcome to StackOverflow.

Can you provide an example of the tuples that you are inserting? I would guess that they are not formatted correctly.

SQL likes to see values formatted like below:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
```

Are you appending the values correctly?

Try converting your tuple to that format. The following code may help:

```
def iter_to_val(iter_in):
    new_list = []
    for item in iter_in:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            new_item = item.replace("'", "_").replace('"', "")
        else:
            new_item = str(item)
        new_list.append(new_item)
    str_out = ', '.join("'" + item + "'" for item in new_list)
    return str_out
```

Note that this code will work for iterables that contain only castable data types ie, if you try to pass a list of complex objects it will break.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I am trying to insert integers, not strings. Due to this this code you wrote can't be used for the tuples.

Comment: Hi UFO, one of the great thing about Python is that tuples are iterable (see a link https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-iterate-through-a-tuple-in-Python here). I have edited the code to make it work for non-strings as well.

Comment: I just realised my mistake, the format was fine, I just forgot to commit. But thanks a lot for your help!